# AWS: To redirect or to proxy files

Tags: proxy, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Let me explain dilemma.
I use 3 services from Amazon: EC2, S3 and CloudFront.
EC2 receives an file as upload, stores it in the S3 bucket. Then CloudFront mirrors the S3 bucket. The only limit is to have user friendly URLs.
Which approach to deliver those files is better?

**Client > CloudFront > EC2 > S3**

- Client does a HTTP request to CloudFront URL
- Cloudfront forwards the request to EC2
- EC2 translates user friendly URL to raw file URL
- EC2 reads the file from S3

**Client > EC2 ... redirect ... CloudFront > S3**

- Client does a HTTP request to EC2
- EC2 translates user friendly URL to raw file URL
- EC2 redirects to CloudFront, witch mirrors the S3

There are two dimensions for this: the speed and the cost.

---

I see facebook using the second approach when serving profile images
http://graph.facebook.com/platform/picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly don't want to force the file transfer between S3 and your client to go through your EC2 instance. That will add load to the EC2 instance, increase bandwidth usage, and undoubtedly slow the response to the user.

Your EC2 instance gives you the greatest control over URL format, so you'll want the client to make the initial request to it (to have a "user-friendly" URL). The EC2 instance can just send the client a redirect to the CloudFront or S3 URL that actually has the content, and the client will pull it directly from there without the further involvement of EC2.

I wouldn't bother with CloudFront unless you have an enormous number of requests, or network latency has to be as low as possible.

Comment: So, I will go with the redirect approach. CloudFront isn't a necessity but I think will be a good thing for marketing.

Comment: I’ve noticed the latency (time to first byte) of a file can vary from 120ms-400ms for a file in S3 and even upwards of 800ms on our occasionally slow wireless connection at work. Cloudfront on the other hand has a latency as low as 18ms, which is no joke. I would hardly rule out using it. More background on it here: http://readystate4.com/2012/07/09/amazon-s3-vs-amazon-cloudfront/

Answer (score 1):

I personally would just give the files a nice name and a proper content type metatag in S3 when first doing the file upload and, as such, remove your EC2 instances from the download path altogether.  You would just serve the clean-url to you client in your HTML content and that clean URL will point directly to you resources in Cloudfront/S3, which has the proper metatags to serve up the desired content-type header.

Comment: This is not an option for me. The URL must be very user friendly.

Comment: @Andrew You can make the URL as friendly as you like.  You can use a CNAME for your domain of choice for Cloudfront and you can name the files whatever you want.  There is absolutely no reason that an image file needs to have .jpg, .png, etc. at the end of it if you send the proper content-type headers.  By naming the files with a user-friendly name in S3, you can eliminate the need to redirect through your server altogether. There is no reason whatsoever to make your web server have to handle 20+ times more requests (depending on number of images/files you would redirect) than it has to.

Comment: What Mike says here 110%. As for Facebook, last I checked, they also do dynamic resizing and that why they pull from their cloud serverside—something they can afford to do. For you, though, I would give the file a nice name, upload to s3, then serve the file via the cloudfront URL. You can create an A Record at your domains DNS so that you can give your Cloudfront a prettier name like files.yoursite.com.